# Validity of creating a statistical model in which a portion of the predictors can be optional

Tags: predictive-models, experiment-design

Suppose I want to construct a model to predict some outcome (the outcome and type of model is inconsequential). The universe of predictors for my problem is `{x, y, z}`. `x` and `y` are derived from one data source; `z` from another. All three of these predictors are deemed "significant" and compose my final model. Additionally, all are fully populated and available when training the model.

I'm interested, however, to know whether I could use this model in the absence of any of the above predictors. Suppose `z` may not be available at the time of prediction, for whatever reason. `z` is nonetheless a crucial predictor, but can I still use this model and process `z` in an appropriate way? Here are two examples of how `z` might be processed, depending on the model type:

1. In the case of a linear/logistic regression model, `z` would have a coefficient. Simply set the missing value for `z` to 0 to nullify the coefficient's effect on the prediction.
2. In the case of a model with more automatic interaction terms, e.g. a tree-based model, I'm not exactly sure how best to handle the complete missingness of `z` in preprocessing, since my assumption is that `z` would be available for all training data. Perhaps some form of imputation might work...

**Is it valid, from a statistical standpoint, to have *one* model like this, that could work in the presence or absence of certain predictors, provided they were handled accordingly?** Suppose I have *n* customers that provide these `{x, y, z}` data to me, and I train a model using all that info. Then I have a new customer who can only provide `x` and `y`, for whatever reason. It seems somewhat wrong to make the assumption that the data-generating process for the new customer, who cannot provide an accurate picture of `z`, would be similar enough to what the model currently represents.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to handle this, but they are not the ones you describe.  One strategy would be to *impute* the missing variable $z$.  This would mean that you would use a model which assumes $z$ is known, and in cases where $z$ is not known, it is inferred based on patterns in the design matrix used to fit the model (I'm not an expert in imputation, so I leave that with you to explore).

Imputation makes a point estimate for the missing data.  That may or may not be desirable.  Another (Bayesian) approach would be to make assumptions on the population distribution of $z$ and then integrate over the uncertainty in $z$ and model uncertainty as well.

I'll revisit this later tonight and perhaps add some exposition.